# Android SparseArray in class parcelable

Tags: android, sparse-matrix, parcelable, serializable

I've a sparsearray in my class named "test".

"test" implements "parcelable", and I want to be able to retrieve my sparsearray between two activities when I'm passing an object Test with an Intent like this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("myObjectTest", myObjectTest);
```

I see there is the method "writeSparseArray", but it doesn't work with my sparsearray.

My current code :

```
public Test(Parcel in) {
     this.id = in.readInt();
     // how to get the sparsearray ?
} 

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    // how can I parse my SparseArray ?
}
```

Comment: Which kind of objects is SparseArray storing?

Comment: It's a class I had made, which implements parcelable.

Answer (score -2):

You can use readSparseArray() and writeSparseArray()

Example:

```
public Test(Parcel in) {
     this.id = in.readInt();
     in.readSparseArray(OBJECT_STORED.class.getClassLoader());
} 

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeSparseArray(mSparseArray);
}
```

**EDIT**

put the parcelable in a Bundle and put this bundle into the intent

Example:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("myObjectTest", test);
intent.putExtra("myBundleTest",bundle);
```

Comment: Nop, I almost tried and it doesn't work like I said.

Comment: "The method writeSparseArray(SparseArray<Object>) in the type Parcel is not applicable for the arguments 
 (SparseArray<MyClassParcelable>)"

Comment: Check this link, Hope it help you: https://gist.github.com/kaushikgopal/9eea148a2188dc58fe37